# How can I add a number to each element of a tuple?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

```
hid = []
for counter,value in enumerate(alist):
    idx1 = np.where(attr['xval'].values == value[0])  #Find Serial index 
    idx2 = np.where(attr['xval'].values == value[1])
    hid.append(idx1)
    hid.append(idx2)
```

This gives me this `hid`

```
[(array([7467]),),
 (array([7473]),),
 (array([7403]),),
 (array([7410]),),
 (array([7386]),),
 (array([7409]),),
 (array([7380]),),
 (array([7439]),),]
```

All, I want is to have a list/array of these values and add `1` to each value.

`print(idx1[0])+1`

`Error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Is there a better way to do this? Since Tuples are immutable, how can I do this?

## alist

```
[array([511, 517], dtype=int32),
 array([447, 454], dtype=int32),
 array([430, 453], dtype=int32),
 array([424, 483], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: Why do you create `hid` and then use `print(idx1[0])+1`?

Comment: `print(idx1[0])` returns nothing. Suggestion: remove redundant information, just provide what you want exactly.  I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: So yeah, two issues there. The `+1` needs to be inside `print()` but I also don't understand why you create `hid` and then start referencing `idx1`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: A tuple is immutable in the sense that it's object pointers can't be changed.  But if those objects themselves are mutable, they can be changed - inplace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
hid = [(array([7467]),),
       (array([7473]),),
       (array([7403]),),
       (array([7410]),),
       (array([7386]),),
       (array([7409]),),
       (array([7380]),),
       (array([7439]),)]
```

Now, every element is a list, so hid is a list of lists. If that is what you want, no problem, but if you want to convert it to a flat list, use `hid = np.array(hid).flatten()`, to get a flat array like `hid = [7467, 7473, 7403, 7410, 7386, 7409, 7380, 7439]`.

To print each value with +1, either just

```
hid_plus_one = tuple(np.array(hid)+1)
print(hid_plus_one)
```

Or

```
hid_plus_one = tuple(v+1 for v in hid)
print(hid_plus_one)
```

That is, if you want to have it as a tuple, or else you can skip the `tuple(..)`-part

Comment: You're welcome, I've added a minor change to address the issue that you have a list of arrays of numbers, and not just a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

numpy will broadcast addition of a scalar over each array

```
alst = [np.array([511, 517], dtype=np.int32),
 np.array([447, 454], dtype=np.int32),
 np.array([430, 453], dtype=np.int32),
 np.array([424, 483], dtype=np.int32)]

alst
Out[4]: [array([511, 517]), array([447, 454]), array([430, 453]), array([424, 483])]


[ary + 1 for ary in alst]
Out[6]: [array([512, 518]), array([448, 455]), array([431, 454]), array([425, 484])]
```